# How do I get my List Items to move up a Little in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am new to this and need a little help. 
Just designing a random website for some practice and I can't seem to get my topmenu on my header to move up. I've changed padding's & margins in a few places and can't seem to get it to work. Wonder if I'm missing something or if there is a better way to organize my CSS. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

```
#main {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 800px;
}

body {
    margin:0;
}

#topbar {
    background-color: black;
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom:0;
    font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#text {
    display:block;
    color: White;
    float:right;
    padding-right: 820px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    font-size:20px;
}

#topmenu {
    display:block;
    list-style:none;
    padding:0 400px 0px 0px;
    float: right;

}

#topmenu li {
    display: inline;
}

#topmenu a {
    position:relative;
    padding:0 4px 0 4px;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-decoration:none;

}

#topmenu a, #topmenu a:visited, #topmenu a:active {
    color:white;
}
```

[I want the menu to move up ever so slightly.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3ti7.png)

```
<div id="topbar" >
<div id="text"><strong>My Template Website</strong></div>
<div id="topmenu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href=""/>Home</li>
        <li><a href=""/>About Us</li>
        <li><a href=""/>Services</li>
        <li><a href=""/>Product</li>
        <li><a href=""/>Contact Us</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: It will be helpful if you can provide the full code with HTML

Comment: There's probably padding/margin in the element above your menu. Either way, we can't help with just that snippet of CSS.

Comment: please provide HTML snippet.

Comment: Done :) @webdeveloper

Comment: Marvin's answer is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you already reduced the margin-bottom of the headline and the margin-top of your topmenu to 0 and now you need a way of bringing the topmenu up a bit more without absolute positioning. What you might not know is, that it is allowed to use a negative margin on the menu to bring it up:

```
#topmenu {
  /* ... your other styles */
  margin-top: -15px;
}
```

Before applying this you shoud check the margin of your `ul` which probably has a margin by the browsers default stylesheet:

[image: Debugging in the Firefox console]

You can check this by yourself when debugging the page in the web console (all popular browsers have one; e.g. in Firefox you have to press F12).

I don't know what the rest of your site looks like and if the surrounding `div#topmenu` is really required. But if not, you could remove it and give the id to the `ul`, then remove the margin-top from your *new* #topmenu. The advantage of this is that you don't have to manage two different elements, which possibly was the reason for your confusion in this example.

```
<div id="topbar" >
  <div id="text"><strong>My Template Website</strong></div> <!-- <h1> instead for semantic reasons? -->
  <ul id="topmenu">
    <li><a href=""/>Home</li>
    <li><a href=""/>About Us</li>
    <li><a href=""/>Services</li>
    <li><a href=""/>Product</li>
    <li><a href=""/>Contact Us</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes! That did it. Thankyou Marvin! :)

Comment: Glad I could help. Make sure to [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235), to inform others that the issue is resolved (and to make me happy about getting some extra reputation hehe).